# Iterate over "1 or more" elements in iterator object?

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, conditional-statements

I'm trying to find an elegant way of doing this. I basically have a class which returns records.
I use a basic iterator for this:

```
i = 0
if mode == "sim":
   for record in iterator_obj:
     try:

      s.sendall(record) 
      time.sleep(delay)
      i += 1
```

However this iterator class has been modified so that if a commandline switch is used, it returns a tuple of (record, delay).

This delay I use in the 
    time.sleep(delay)

And this looks like this (which will obviously fail if the iterator doesn't return the delay):

```
for record, wait in iterator_obj:

    if wait == 0:
      pass
    else:
      delay = wait
      if verbose:
        print ('\n[+] Waiting {} seconds to send next record'.format(delay))


    try:

      s.sendall(record) 
      time.sleep(delay)
      i += 1
```

Its a lot of wasted lines, is there a way to do a conditional for loop for 1 or more elements?

```
for x, y (if y) in iterator_object
```

**solution**

The trick was to use isinstance to check for tuple. Updated code below:

```
for record in iterator_obj:

  wait = None
  if isinstance(record,(list,tuple)):
    record,wait = record

  if wait == 0 or wait is None:
      pass
  else:
    delay = wait
    if verbose:
        print ('\n[+] Waiting {} seconds to send next record'.format(delay))
```

Comment: What about changing the first one to return tuples of `(record, 0)` (or whatever default delay), and use the same code path for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for record in myList:
    wait = None
    if isinstance(record,(list,tuple)):
       record,wait = record
```

might be what your want ...

Comment: or `record, wait = ele if isinstance(ele, tuple) else ele,None`

Comment: Yep that solves it. First time using isinstance. Thanks!

I'll update my question with the fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is a bit over the top, but I think it does what you want. Still, this probably isn't what you are looking for as it is a rather ugly expression. Here is an example of how it works:

```
In [1]: iterable = [(1,2), (0,1), 2, 4]
In [2]: [(lambda *z: isinstance(z[0], tuple) and z[0] or (z[0], 0))(x) for x in iterable
Out[2]: [(1, 2), (0, 1), (2, 0), (4, 0)]
```

The last term is an iterable, which should be replaced with your iterator. Every element that this returns is run through the [lambda function](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) which uses the [and-or trick](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html) to return either a the original tuple, or the integer inside a tuple with the second element set to zero.

Essentially, it allows you to deal with the multiple forms of input, as you requested. But it is less readable than what you wanted.

Comment: I used another answer, but saved yours as it looks pleasantly complex. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple choices:

- always have the `iterator_obj` return both the record and the delay, and just ignore the delay when you don't need it:

  `for record, _ in iterator_obj`
- make a different method to return a different iterator:

  `for record, delay in iterajtor_obj.iterate_with_delay()`

Comment: This is probably the correct way to go, but for the time being I'm unable to change the class which returns the record/wait to make it uniform.

Answer (score 0):

take a list for example:

```
l=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
[(x,y) for x,y in list if y>2]
```

this output [(2, 3), (3, 4)]
hope this helpful.

Comment: I don't think I can evaluate y (y>2) if its not even being returned.